# Getting facebook stream updates for a mobile application (Android or iOS)

Tags: android, ios, facebook-graph-api, push-notification

I want to use the Facebook API for getting stream updates to my mobile application running on Android or iOS. I did some research and I can see that I can use the Facebook API calls (graph API or FQL) straight from the mobile device (not necessarily go through an intermediate server).

But, I want to get Facebook updates in the background, even if the application is not running.

So, since I am new to mobile development, my questions are:

1. If the application is not running (not explicitly opened by the user) can I get updates to the application using the application's code, or should I use an intermediate server that would send the notifications to the application?
2. Should I have a server in the middle to send notifications when the application is not active.

I simply need to understand if I need to develop a server accessing Facebook besides the mobile application if I want to receive notifications when the mobile app is not active.

Answer (score 0):

A server is not necessarily required.

The most basic implementation of this could retrieve an access_token from [facebook sdk](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/) adding the [offline_access](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) option to your permissions request.

Then you can use an android [alarmmanager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to "wake up" your app periodically.  The broadcast receiver can perform whatever updates you want to make from the facebook api and it doesn't necessarily ever have to show anything to the user.

Comment: thats good enough.
do u know if it works like that for iOS as well?

Comment: it's similar but i do not know ios' implementation of alarmmanager

Answer (score 0):

For Android use a background service, these are specifically designed to run in the background  even after a user closes your app.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html